# Moving files based on CSV values

Tags: csv, batch-file

noobie here.

I have a csv file with two columns, they specify source files paths and destinated paths. I have around 1500+ lines to execute. Is there any way to batch process this via a bat file or anything else?

A line in my CSV looks like this:

```
Source Path,Dest Path
C:\Users\Nick\Pictures\XXXXXXX.img,C:\Users\Nick\Pictures\Export\XXXXXXX.img
```

Comment: `FOR /F "SKIP=1 USEBACKQ TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=," %%G IN ("myfile.csv") DO echo source=%%G destination=%%H`

Comment: @Squashman: Careful, this might break when paths contain commas and the fields are quoted.

Comment: …however @Joey, a record containing an unquoted field with string data using one or more commas, is not technically a working Comma Separated Value!

Comment: @Compo: Hence I said quoted, yes. But the presence of such things require that your field splitting is quote-aware, which almost all trivial options are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably not solve this with batch files, but rather with PowerShell. It's possible in batch, but notoriously unreliable, especially around characters you don't expect when starting out.

In PowerShell this could be as simple as

```
Import-Csv files.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.'Source Path' -Destination $_.'Dest Path'
}
```

You might need to create directories as required, perhaps something like this:

```
Import-Csv files.csv | ForEach-Object {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory (Split-Path -Parent $_.'Source Path')
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.'Source Path' -Destination $_.'Dest Path'
}
```

Comment: Hi Joey! Thanks for the prompt reply! It's works quite well, except it shows up "Illegal characters in path" during whatIF run. Most of my files are in multilingual and I've enabled "beta UFT-8" settings in windows. I've also double-check my CSV to make sure no spacing etc. How would I solve this? I've counted up to around 10+ errors so I can also do the sorting manually. Is there anyway to add a log file?

Comment: @NickLi, as the command you have used above does not specify a particular file encoding for your input CSV. As newer versions of PowerShell use `utf8NoBOM` by default I must assume that you are using an older version, probably PowerShell v5.1. Older versions use your default system's active code page _(probably ANSI)_. I would therefore suggest that you try it by specifying a different encoding. I would advise UTF-8, so change `Import-Csv files.csv` to `Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'S;\omeFolder\MyFile.csv' -Encoding UTF8`. and try it again.

Comment: @Compo Hi, thanks! It's now displaying the right text using UTF8.